# Almost sure convergence of a function and its argument

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, almost-everywhere

> If $f_n(x)\xrightarrow{a.s}f(x)$ and $t_n\xrightarrow{a.s}t$ as ${n \to \infty}$, is this always true that $f_n(t_n)\xrightarrow{a.s}f(t)$ as ${n \to \infty}$?

Note that $t_n \xrightarrow{a.s} t$ means $t_n$ converges to $t$ almost surely, in other words, $P(\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}t_n=t)=1$.

To solve this problem, I have to conclude $P(\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}f_n(t_n)=f(t))=1$ from $P(\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}f_n(x)=f(x))=1$ and $P(\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}t_n=t)=1$.

Thus, If I prove $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}f_n(t_n)=f(t)$ from $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}t_n=t$, the proof is complete. How can I prove this?

Comment: What do you know about convergence of both limits in your question?

Comment: @DonLarynx I edited the problem to add more information, it is almost sure convergence

Answer (score 1):

Note that:

$$ f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x) \quad iff  \quad (f_n(x)-f(x))\rightarrow0$$

So that one can write

$$ f_n(t_n)-f(t)=f_n(t_n)-f(t_n)+(f(t_n)-f(t)) $$

Of course $f_n(t_n)-f(t_n) \rightarrow 0 $, to prove your assumption, we need to prove: $f(t_n)-f(t) \rightarrow 0$, that hold if $f$ is continuos in $t$

On the other hand, if $f$ is not continuos in t$ this no longer holds, consider as a counter example:

Suppose $f=1$ for $x\geq 0$  and 0 otherwhise, $t_n=-1/n \quad tn \rightarrow0$ as but $f(t_n)=0 \ \  \forall n $ so it cannot converge to $f(0)=1$

Comment: Yeah, but $t_n  \xrightarrow{a.s.} t$ so therefore after large enough $n$, $f(t_n)$ behaves like $f(t)$.

Comment: Suppose f=1 for x\geq 0 and 0 otherwhise, tn=-1/n tn->0 as but f(tn)=0 \forall n so it cannot converge to f(0)=1

Comment: So it's not true in that case, and therefore can't always be true.

Comment: How about the case that f is not continious?

Comment: I edited my answer to include a counter example